# calling an activity from stack instead of launching new instance

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

how can i call an activity from stack instead of launching new instance ?
here is a scenario :

1. calling activity A with parameters in order to retrieve data
2. navigate from A to B
3. navigate from B to C
4. i want launch A again but not with a new instance , i want get it from the stack so no need to pass parameters and wait to retrieve data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your point correctly you can simple exit your activity B and C with `finish();`.

So if you ActivityC finishes and also ActivityB the ActivityA should come to the front, which should be that what you want.

Comment: the problem is that i want that all activity stay in the stack so i can use them later instead of creating new instance , cos all of them need parameters to get data , so the point is calling a new instance once and then get it back from the stack

Comment: I don't know how to go sideways in the stack just now sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT). For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BActivity.this, AActivity.class);     
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

From javadocs:

> public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT 
>   Added in API
>   level 3
>
> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's
>   history stack if it is already running.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of four activities: A, B, C,
>   D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then B will be brought to the front of the
>   history stack, with this resulting order: A, C, D, B. This flag will
>   be ignored if FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is also specified.